# Keyboard shortcut to change tabs in terminal not working anymore in yosemite

Tags: terminal, macos, shortcut

I've set up a custom shortcut for Terminal to change tabs: `cmd+option+left/right` (the same as in most browsers, for convenience).

I did this by going to `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts` and adding it to Terminal as shortcuts for "Select Next Tab" and "Select Previous Tab". It worked perfectly.

Two days ago, I've upgraded to OS X Yosemite and now it's not working anymore. When I browse to the same location in System Preferences, it's configured. But it doesn't work.

How do I fix this, and more importantly, **why** is this happening?

Comment: There are default Cmd+Shift+']' shortcuts for changing tabs, shared by all tab-based Mac apps (Safari, Xcode, etc.), since at least 10.8, why would you make your own ones for Terminal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The menu option `Select Previous Tab` is changed to `Show Previous Tab` and there is by default key shortcut for it

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd>  Show Next Tab

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>  Show Previous Tab

Answer (score 2):

It appears Apple renamed Terminal menus from `Select Next Tab` to `Show Next Tab`. Same for `Previous`. If you just rename the menu titles in your Keyboard Shortcuts accordingly, your shortcuts should start working again.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the problem: If you want your old shortcuts back, you can go into `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts` , then rename your shortcuts of `Select Previous Tab` and `Select Next Tab` to `Show Previous Tab` and `Show Next Tab` respectively. The naming here matters in order for you to see results when you re-open your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I boarded the struggle bus on this for many days. If the change in syntax from 'Show Previous Tab' to "Select Previous Tab" mentioned above doesn't work for you, you'll need to make sure you check that whatever your desired shortcut isn't already defined somewhere else in the 'system preferences.' In my case, my favorite tab shortcut of control-arrow was reserved for a mission control shortcut that wasn't reserved in Mavericks. The switch to Yosemite led to the discrepancy and cost me too much head scratching.